# Retrieval Prism and two-handed weapons

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e

When you activate [Retrieval Prism](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1032), the attuned item immediately teleports "*into your hand*". If it is a two-handed item like a Bladed Scarf, can you attack with it on your next action, or do you have to spend another action to grab it with your other hand?

Comment: Our ["How to ask a good question"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) help article suggests sharing any research you have already done toward solving your problem, and I'm noticing a pattern of asking brief questions without some of the things suggested in that article. Of course, not every question needs such details, and sometimes we just don't know where to begin our research for our questions, but any time you can provide some details of your own research or reasoning, those things would be helpful - it might help point others to where the confusion is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Spend another action (sorry, not sorry)

While the explicit use of "hand" doesn't cement that it must be interpreted literally... I see no justification to go out of your way to provide a *more* lenient reading than the literal. The fact that it's limited to 1 Bulk or less also suggests that it was not really designed to be used with 2-handed weapons, which are mostly 2 Bulk (obviously not a reason to restrict it, but more fuel for not providing a fringe benefit).

Comment: http://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=194
"If you retrieve a two-handed item with only one hand, you still need to change your grip before you can wield or use it." is the only rule I can find relating your first claim. It seems that you can draw a weapon and wield it with one action provided that you use two hands to do so.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if I misread that or if it's been changed. I didn't see before that you can Retrieve an item with two hands. Although I'm going to keep the ruling stipulated here in my games since it makes sense (there aren't a lot of scabbard placements that you can draw with both hands placed correctly on the hilt) and keeps the action economy verisimilitude. I'll look at revising the answer, but I don't think losing that point invalidates the conclusion

Comment: There was quite a bit of errata around item retrieval and storage, so it's possible this was the target of such an errata.